# Multiple threads attempting to lock

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

I want to use pthreads and pthread_mutexes in a C++ program.  I don't have any actual code yet, just a question on how mutexes work.  If I have thread 1 lock a mutex, then n number of other threads attempt to lock that same mutex, what will the behavior be when thread 1 unlocks the mutex?  If thread 1 acquires the lock, then thread 2 attempts to lock, then thread 3 attempts to lock, will thread 2 have priority over thread 3 when the lock is released?

Here is a more organized timeline of the locking would look:

```
thread 1 acquires lock
thread 2 attempts to lock
thread 3 attempts to lock
thread 4 attempts to lock
thread 1 unlocks mutex
??
```

in other words, I'd like the threads to execute in the order in which they attempt to acquire the lock/are created.  if there is a better way to do this, I'm more than open to suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No - there will be no such guaranteed ordering. After thread 1 releases the mutex thread 3 could get or thread 2 could get it. You can't predict that.

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280712/how-to-allow-certain-threads-to-have-priority-in-locking-a-mutex-use-pthreads?rq=1) for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I figured I'd post my solution so others could see a potential fix:

My main thread is the thread that creates worker threads by locking a creation mutex and putting each thread into a `std::queue`.

at the start of main, I create a manager thread and that is in an infinite while loop which checks to see if the queue is empty every cycle. when the manager thread sees the queue is nonempty 
(`if(! queue::empty())`), it waits to acquire the lock and then creates the front thread, pops it from the queue, executes a pthread_join() on the thread and loops back around for the next thread.