# Signalling to threads waiting at a lock that the lock has become irrelevant

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

I have a hash table implementation in C where each location in the table is a linked list (to handle collisions). These linked lists are inherently thread safe and so no additional thread-safe code needs to be written at the hash table level if the table is a constant size - the hash table is thread-safe.

However, I would like the hash table to dynamically expand as values were added so as to maintain a reasonable access time. For the table to expand though, it needs additional thread-safety.

For the purposes of this question, procedures which can safely occur concurrently are 'benign' and the table resizing procedure (which cannot occur concurrently) is 'critical'. Threads currently using the list are known as 'users'.

My first solution to this was to put 'preamble' and 'postamble' code for all the critical function which locks a mutex and then waits until there are no current users proceeding. Then I added preamble and postamble code to the benign functions to check if a critical function was waiting, and if so to wait at the same mutex until the critical section is done.

In pseudocode the pre/post-amble functions SHOULD look like:

```
benignPreamble(table) {
    if (table->criticalIsRunning) {
        waitUntilSignal;
    }
    incrementUserCount(table);
}

benignPostamble(table) {
    decrementUserCount(table);
}

criticalPreamble(table) {
    table->criticalIsRunning = YES;
    waitUntilZero(table->users);
}

criticalPostamble(table) {
    table->criticalIsRunning = NO;
    signalCriticalDone();
}
```

My actual code is shown at the bottom of this question and uses (perhaps unnecessarily) [caf's PriorityLock from this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280712/how-to-allow-certain-threads-to-have-priority-in-locking-a-mutex-use-pthreads). My implementation, quite frankly, [smells awful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). What is a better way to  handle this situation? At the moment I'm looking for a way to signal to a mutex that it is irrelevant and 'unlock all waiting threads' simultaneously, but I keep thinking there must be a simpler way. I am trying to code it in such a way that any thread-safety mechanisms are 'ignored' if the critical process is not running.

---

**Current Code**

```
void startBenign(HashTable *table) {

    // Ignores if critical process can't be running (users >= 1)
    if (table->users == 0) {
        // Blocks if critical process is running
        PriorityLockLockLow(&(table->lock));
        PriorityLockUnlockLow(&(table->lock));
    }
    __sync_add_and_fetch(&(table->users), 1);

}

void endBenign(HashTable *table) {
    // Decrement user count (baseline is 1)
    __sync_sub_and_fetch(&(table->users), 1);
}

int startCritical(HashTable *table) {

    // Get the lock
    PriorityLockLockHigh(&(table->lock));

    // Decrement user count BELOW baseline (1) to hit zero eventually
    __sync_sub_and_fetch(&(table->users), 1);

    // Wait for all concurrent threads to finish
    while (table->users != 0) {
        usleep(1);
    }

    // Once we have zero users (any new ones will be
    // held at the lock) we can proceed.
    return 0;
}

void endCritical(HashTable *table) {

    // Increment back to baseline of 1
    __sync_add_and_fetch(&(table->users), 1);

    // Unlock
    PriorityLockUnlockHigh(&(table->lock));
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the mutex wait function return a special status when the mutex is deleted and threads are waiting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to reinvent the reader-writer lock, which I believe pthreads provides as a primitive.  Have you tried using that?

More specifically, your benign functions should be taking a "reader" lock, while your critical functions need a "writer" lock.  The end result will be that as many benign functions can execute as desired, but when a critical function starts executing it will wait until no benign functions are in process, and will block additional benign functions until it has finished.  I think this is what you want.