# Null arguments to pthread_cond_wait

Tags: c, null, pthreads, condition-variable

If a thread calls pthread_cond_wait(cond_ptr,mutex_ptr) will a *null* cond_ptr, is it guaranteed to not fall asleep?

According to http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread_cond_wait.html,
a null cond_ptr just means pthread_cond_wait()  *may* (not an emphatic **will**) fail, so I guess threads can then fall asleep on null condition variables?

Comment: In the link that you posted it actually says: "[EINVAL]
The value specified by cond, mutex, or abstime is invalid." I don't think a null cond_ptr is allowed

Comment: But it says "may" fail, for my application I'd need it to be a guaranteed "will".

Comment: I think the "may" means "as opposed to crash", not "as opposed to succeed". null doesn't work for this function (and in any case - it's easy to check)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see a valid use case for this and I'm wondering why it would ever matter. You shouldn't *be* calling `pthread_cond_wait` with an invalid condition variable.

If you're worried about it, just change your code from:

```
pthread_cond_wait (pcv, pmutex);
```

to something like:

```
if (pcv != NULL) pthread_cond_wait (pcv, pmutex);
```

and it won't be called with a NULL.

I suspect it was put in as "may" simply because there was an implementation of pthreads (perhaps even the original DEC threads itself) which didn't return a failure code for that circumstance.

But, since the alternative is almost certainly that the whole thing fell in a screaming heap, I wouldn't be relying on it :-)

---

If you're worried about the atomicity of that code, you needn't be. Simply use the same mutex that protects the condition variable to protect the CV pointer being held in your list:

```
claim mutex A
somenode->cv = NULL
release mutex A
```

and, in your looping code:

```
claim mutex A
if loopnode->cv != null:
    wait on condvar loopnode->cv using mutex A
// mutex A is locked again
: : :
```

The fact that the mutex is locked during both the `if` and calling `pthread_condvar_wait` means that no race condition can exist. Nothing can change the node condition variables until the looping thread releases the mutex within the `pthread_condvar_wait` call. And by that time, the call is using its own local copy of the pointer so changing te one in the list will have no effect.

And, if the node-changing code grabs the mutex, the `if` and `pthread_condvar_wait` can't execute until that mutex is released.

Comment: @ManRow, then my suggestion is to use the `if` variant in the answer. In other words, only attempt to call `pthread_cond_wait()` if the node has a non-NULL CV in it.

Comment: Your posted solution is non-atomic and will fail if "pcv" is set to NULL after the if-statement (i.e, the classic ABA problem, of course!). That is why I need a _guaranteed_ pthread_cond_wait() fail on a null condition variable pointer.

Comment: No, it _is_ atomic since you are required to have a lock on the mutex before calling `cv_wait`. You just use the same mutex when attempting to change the CV _anywhere._ The entry and exit conditions before calling `cv_wait` or that `if` variant are the same: mutex locked. Changing the pointer in the _node_ won't affect the cv being waited on in the call (when the mutex is unlocked) since the old pointer value has already been passed in.

Comment: That is a good point; essentially, the problem (in my program) then is rather a **misuse** of pthread_cond_wait() _functionality_, than pthread_cond_wait() _itself_. I would like to ask then (while on that topic), whether it is possible for a thread that _locked_ a mutex to somehow "query" whether any other threads are currently blocked on it?

Comment: No, not portably. You may want to open another question with the detail so you get a wider response than just me :-)

Comment: Thank you for suggesting `pthread_mutex_trylock` operation. In the event that a thread is blocked trying to lock a mutex currently locked by some other thread, and that other thread calls pthread_mutex_unlock() right before calling pthread_mutex_unlock() on that same mutex, is the originally locked thread guaranteed not to starve?

Comment: I actually suggested trylock but realised it didn't sit with your requirement for the current lock holder to determine if _another_ thread was waiting. It's more suited to a thread finding out if it can lock the mutex but not blocking. And, no, I don't think you can guarantee non-starvation if one thread is doing unlock/lock quickly (assuming that's what you meant rather than unlock/unlock as you stated). That's why you use things like condvars so that mutexes don't starve your threads.

Comment: A good solution might be to implement a "ticket-lock"-type mutex, as described here --> [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050083/linux-synchronization-with-fifo-waiting-queue)