# Boost IPC condition variable blocks after one process crashes and restart

Tags: c++, boost, ipc, condition-variable

I have an `interprocess` `condition variable` to sync my processes, there is one `notifier` that `notify` and two `waiters` that `timed_wait` for `notification` or `timeout`.

If one of the `waiters` crashes and restarts, the three processes are blocked.

The way to fix it is to kill them, delete the shared memory, and restart them.

Processes sync shared memory class:

```
class ProcessSync {
public:
    static ProcessSync *OpenOrCreate(bip::managed_shared_memory &sync_segment, const std::string& sync_name) {
        while (true) {
            std::string object_name = sync_name + OBJECT_NAME;
            std::string lock_name = sync_name + LOCK;
            try {
                bip::named_mutex sync_lock{bip::open_or_create, lock_name.c_str()};
                bip::scoped_lock<bip::named_mutex> lock(sync_lock, boost::get_system_time() + boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
                if (lock) {
                    sync_segment = {bip::open_or_create, sync_name.c_str(),
                                               int(sizeof(ProcessSync) * 10)};
                    return (sync_segment.find_or_construct<ProcessSync>(
                        (object_name.c_str()))());
                } else {
                    LOG(WARNING) << "can't acquire lock for opening the " + sync_name;
                    throw std::exception();
                }
            } catch (std::exception &e) {
                LOG(WARNING) << "ProcessSync could not be created.";
                LOG(WARNING) << e.what();
                RemoveShmByName(sync_name);
                RemoveLockByName(lock_name);
                sleep(10);
            }
        }
    }

    static ProcessSync *Open(bip::managed_shared_memory &sync_segment, const std::string& sync_name) {
        while (true) {
            std::string object_name = sync_name + OBJECT_NAME;
            std::string lock_name = sync_name + LOCK;
            try {
                bip::named_mutex sync_lock{bip::open_only, lock_name.c_str()};
                bip::scoped_lock<bip::named_mutex> lock(sync_lock, bip::try_to_lock);
                if (lock) {
                    sync_segment = bip::managed_shared_memory(bip::open_only, sync_name.c_str());
                    return sync_segment.find<ProcessSync>(object_name.c_str()).first;
                } else {
                    LOG(WARNING) << "can't acquire lock for opening the shm " + sync_name;
                    throw std::exception();
                }
            } catch (std::exception &e) {
                LOG(WARNING) << sync_name + " shm not set yet.";
                LOG(WARNING) << e.what();
                sleep(5);
            }
        }
    }

    static void RemoveLockByName(const std::string & lock_name) {
        try {
            bip::named_mutex::remove(lock_name.c_str());
            LOG(INFO) << lock_name + " deleted.";
        } catch (std::exception &e) {
            LOG(WARNING) << lock_name + " NOT deleted.";
            LOG(WARNING) << e.what();
        }
    }
    
    static void RemoveShmByName(const std::string & sync_name) {
        try {
            bip::shared_memory_object::remove(sync_name.c_str());
            LOG(INFO) << sync_name + " deleted.";
        } catch (std::exception &e) {
            LOG(WARNING) << sync_name + " NOT deleted.";
            LOG(WARNING) << e.what();
        }
    
    }

    void WaitForSyncNotification(int timeout = CV_WAIT_TIMEOUT) {
        bip::scoped_lock<boost::interprocess::interprocess_mutex> lock(process_sync_cv_mutex_);
        bpt::ptime wait_timeout = bpt::second_clock::local_time() + bpt::seconds(timeout);
        process_sync_cv_.timed_wait(lock, wait_timeout);
    }

    void NotifySync(){
        process_sync_cv_.notify_all();
    }

private:
    bip::interprocess_mutex process_sync_cv_mutex_;
    bip::interprocess_condition process_sync_cv_;
};
```

First process `notifier`:

```
bip::managed_shared_memory sync_segment;
ProcessSync *sync = ProcessSync::OpenOrCreate(sync_segment, "sync");
while(){
    //do something
    sync->NotifySync();
}
```

Second/Third processes `waiters`:

```
bip::managed_shared_memory sync_segment;
ProcessSync *sync = ProcessSync::Open(sync_segment, "sync");
while(){
    sync->WaitForSyncNotification();
    //do something
}
```

If the `waiters` crashes while waiting on the `condition variable` it lives in an undefined stage?
How can I avoid it without cleaning the memory in case of a process crash?

[process-shared-condition-variable-how-to-recover-after-one-process-dies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48011696/process-shared-condition-variable-how-to-recover-after-one-process-dies) Talks about the same thing but not in the `boost` lib

##################### Edit #####################

Boost version `1.78.0`

Linux `Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS`

Arch `aarch64`

On a normal run, everything works as expected, and when one `waiter` crashes (non-boost related issues) and restarts the three processes are blocked on the condition variable, `notifier` blocked on `notify`, first `waiter` blocked on `timed_wait`, crashed `waiter` blocked on `mutex lock`.

In case the `notifier` is up but not in the while loop yet, the `waiters` can crash and restart, and the behavior of waiting until timeout will continue, but when the `notifier` enter the while loop and `notify` the three of them get stuck, `notifier` block on `notify`, first `waiter` block on `timed_wait`, crashed `waiter` block on `mutex lock`.

It happened just when I crashed one of the `waiters` when it blocked on `wait`, not when I crashed the `notifier`.

Comment: What's your OS and Boost version? At least for [POSIX mutexes support to handle it should be in place](https://github.com/boostorg/interprocess/commit/7c8893788d3823615d6ddbfd125d2ad153817111) Unless I'm mistaken, the condition variable should automatically be "robust" if its mutex is

Comment: @Homer512 oh that's interesting. I'm still going around warning against non-robustness. Would be nice to test this out for  bit

Comment: @sehe unfortunately it simply drops the mutex in an unrecoverable state. Better than deadlocking but still without recovery option even though both POSIX and Windows can do that. But I guess it would be hard to get this into a normal `unique_lock` or similar since you would need to somehow raise an error while also *technically* acquiring the lock. And then you have to be careful about how to proceed with unlocking