# Shared memory condition variable block after process crash

Tags: c, arm, posix, ipc, condition-variable

I'm running some process with `POSIX` `cond var` on `shared memory`, orig question: [boost-ipc-condition-variable-blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76956994/boost-ipc-condition-variable-blocks-after-one-process-crashes-and-restart).

I run 2, 3 or 4 processes and if one of them stops, the other two get block on the `cond var` or on the `mutex`, it get solved only after the shared memory is deleted and recreated, so I understand that the `cond var` / `mutex` on the shared memory is corrupted.

OS: `Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS`

Arch: `aarch64`

Found this question: [process-shared-condition-variable-how-to-recover-after-one-process-dies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48011696/process-shared-condition-variable-how-to-recover-after-one-process-dies), and implemented the solution using `pthread_mutex_consistent`, but it didn't helped,I put `pthread_mutex_consistent` on several places in the code (after error / after `mutex` lock / after `pthread_cond_timedwait`).
Code:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>

/***************************************************************************************************/

/* Simple ticket lock queue with pthreads
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48011696/process-shared-condition-variable-how-to-recover-after-one-process-dies
 */

typedef struct ticket_lock {
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_cond_t  cond;
    int queue_head, queue_tail;
} ticket_lock_t;

static void
ticket_init(ticket_lock_t *t)
{
    pthread_mutexattr_t mattr;
    pthread_mutexattr_init(&mattr);
    pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&mattr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
    pthread_mutexattr_setrobust(&mattr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_ROBUST);
    pthread_mutex_init(&t->mutex, &mattr);
    pthread_mutexattr_destroy(&mattr);

    pthread_condattr_t cattr;
    pthread_condattr_init(&cattr);
    pthread_condattr_setpshared(&cattr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
    pthread_cond_init(&t->cond, &cattr);
    pthread_condattr_destroy(&cattr);

    t->queue_head = t->queue_tail = 0;
}

static void
ticket_broadcast(ticket_lock_t *ticket)
{
    printf("####### pthread_cond_broadcast\n");
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&ticket->cond);
}

static int
ticket_lock(ticket_lock_t *ticket)
{
    printf("####### pthread_mutex_lock\n");
    pthread_mutex_lock(&ticket->mutex);
    int queue_me = ticket->queue_tail++;

    while (queue_me > ticket->queue_head) {
        time_t sec = time(NULL) + 2;  /* 5s timeout */
        struct timespec ts = { .tv_sec = sec, .tv_nsec = 0 };

        printf("%i: waiting, current: %i  me: %i\n", getpid(), ticket->queue_head, queue_me);

        printf("####### pthread_cond_timedwait\n");
        int ret_wait = pthread_cond_timedwait(&ticket->cond, &ticket->mutex, &ts);
        int err_wait = errno;
        printf("retval_wait: %i\n", ret_wait);
        printf("error_wait: %s\n", strerror(err_wait));
        if (ret_wait == 0)
          continue;

        int ret_consis = pthread_mutex_consistent(&ticket->mutex);
        int err_consis = errno;
        printf("retval_consis: %i\n", ret_consis);
        printf("error_consis: %s\n", strerror(err_consis));
        if (ret_wait == EOWNERDEAD){
                perror("EOWNERDEAD");
        } else if (ret_wait == ETIMEDOUT){
                perror("ETIMEDOUT");
        } else {
              perror("pthread_cond_timedwait");
              exit(1);
        }

        /* Timeout, kick current user... */
        printf("kicking stale ticket %i\n", ticket->queue_head);
        pthread_mutex_consistent(&ticket->mutex);
        ticket->queue_head++;
        ticket_broadcast(ticket);
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&ticket->mutex);
    return queue_me;
}

static void
ticket_unlock(ticket_lock_t *ticket, int me)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&ticket->mutex);
    if (ticket->queue_head == me) {  /* Normal case: we haven't timed out. */
        ticket->queue_head++;
        ticket_broadcast(ticket);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&ticket->mutex);
}


/***************************************************************************************************/
/* Shared memory */

#define SHM_NAME    "fifo_sched"
#define SHM_MAGIC   0xdeadbeef

struct sched_shm {
    int  size;
    int  magic;
    int  ready;

    /* sched stuff */
    ticket_lock_t queue;
};

static unsigned int shm_size = 256;
static struct sched_shm *shm = 0;

/* Create new shared memory segment */
static void
create_shm()
{
       int fd = shm_open(SHM_NAME, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644);
       assert(fd != -1);
       int r = ftruncate(fd, shm_size);  assert(r == 0);
       void *pt = mmap(0, shm_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
       assert(pt != MAP_FAILED);
       fprintf(stderr, "Created shared memory.\n");

       shm = pt;
       memset(shm, 0, sizeof(*shm));
       shm->size = shm_size;
       shm->magic = SHM_MAGIC;
       shm->ready = 0;

       ticket_init(&shm->queue);

       shm->ready = 1;
}

/* Attach existing shared memory segment */
static int
attach_shm()
{
    int fd = shm_open(SHM_NAME, O_RDWR, 0);
    if (fd == -1)  return 0;  /* Doesn't exist yet... */

    shm = mmap(0, shm_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    int err = errno;
    if (shm == MAP_FAILED){
                perror("mmap");
                printf("error: %i", err);
                exit(1);
          }
    fprintf(stderr, "Mapped shared memory.\n");

    assert(shm->magic == SHM_MAGIC);
    assert(shm->ready);
    return 1;
}

static void
shm_init()
{
    fprintf(stderr, "shm_init()\n");
    assert(shm_size >= sizeof(struct sched_shm));
    if (!attach_shm())
        create_shm();
}


/***************************************************************************************************/

int main()
{
    shm_init();

    while (1) {
        int ticket = ticket_lock(&shm->queue);
        printf("%i: start %i\n", getpid(), ticket);
        printf("%i: done  %i\n", getpid(), ticket);
        ticket_unlock(&shm->queue, ticket);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Running 3 processes.
Logs of the first process (before one process crash and blocking):

```
####### pthread_mutex_lock
13254: waiting, current: 484123  me: 484125
####### pthread_cond_timedwait
retval_wait: 0
error_wait: No such file or directory
13254: waiting, current: 484124  me: 484125
####### pthread_cond_timedwait
retval_wait: 0
error_wait: No such file or directory
13254: start 484125
13254: done  484125
####### pthread_cond_broadcast
```

Logs for the Second / Third processes (before one process crash and blocking):

```
####### pthread_mutex_lock
23427: waiting, current: 695284  me: 695286
####### pthread_cond_timedwait
retval_wait: 0
error_wait: Success
23427: waiting, current: 695285  me: 695286
####### pthread_cond_timedwait
retval_wait: 0
error_wait: Success
23427: start 695286
23427: done  695286
####### pthread_cond_broadcast
```

After one process stop the other two are block on the `mutex` lock, the `timedwait` or on the `broadcast`.

Am I using the `pthread_mutex_consistent` wrong? are the `pthread_cond_t` and `pthread_mutex_t` not robust and safe for shared memory multiprocess usage?